# Error loading hyphenation connecting from android studio to azure portal

Tags: android, azure

I'm trying to connect from my android project to azure. There is a example using the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started

I had a couple of questions. Firstly after implementing the basic TodoItem example (but from my project) I keep getting the error below and the app crashes.

```
E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Also re: the azure portal setup for mobile backend clicking quickstart in azure portal for the mobile backend brings up 3 steps. No. 1 is Connect a database and that is ticked with "You already have a data connection" but i didn't setup a dataconnection - so how and where is that done?

Also it gives dependencies to add to Gradle.build - but in my project there's only build.gradle (in the Gradle Scripts folder)...is that the same thing? And what is the difference between build.gradle (Project) and build.gradle (Module)

No2. Says you already have a TodoItem table but again i didn't set this up. So just wondering where it is?

If I wanted to create my own tables and do these steps manually without clicking on quickstart and wondering if there documentation for that? And what is the difference - other than the obvious - between Mobile Apps and Mobile Apps Quickstart in the market place.

Also, when importing the ToDo item project from azure the first time I load it the project needed to download android sdk 23 while i'm running 25.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I don't know whether your project was built by yourself via follow the document. If yes, there is an offical [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-mobile-apps-android-quickstart) for that document, please compare yours with the offical one carefully, especially for [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-mobile-apps-android-quickstart/blob/master/TaskList/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) & [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-mobile-apps-android-quickstart/blob/master/TaskList/app/build.gradle). Per my experience, I think the configuration of your project seems not to be suitable with your AVD settings and missing some permission, so it caused your issue.

The offical sample needs the android sdk version & permission below which are declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And the required `compileSdkVersion` is 23 declared in the `build.gradle` file, so your project needed to download android sdk 23.